# Ansible ntp server + several clients deployment

Tags: ansible, ntp

I know this is kind of a newbie question but: How should I define my hosts file? if I want a NTP server and several clients and still have the ability to do common things to all the hosts?

I have, let's say, 10 servers. One of them will be the NTP server and the rest will sync against it. I could define my hosts file like:

```
[ntp-server]
hostA

[ntp-slaves]
hostB
hostC
hostD
...

[my_servers]
ntp-server
ntp-slaves
```

So, I can apply common config `(ssh, iptables)` to all of them. I can have other classifications like webservers, loadbalancers or any other. So, far I can't figure out how to solve this the "elegant" way.

Also, related to this, should I have two roles? `(ntp_server, ntp_client)` or a single one with differente behaviour if it's inside the client or server group?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but the correct syntax for `my_servers` is :

```
[my_servers:children]
ntp-server
ntp-slaves
```

Yes, Ansible needs a little help when building groups from other groups.

Note that you can combine `[my_servers:children]` (to add groups) and `[my_servers]` (to add hosts) in the same inventory file.

Comment: Thanks! How will Ansible handle groups overlapping? If a host is member of two groups and I apply a playbook over "all" hosts? I've to think a bit about granularity and plan my groups carefully.

Comment: Ansible will sort things out, and do de-duplication (i.e. it won't execute the role twice on the host).